# Flutter flutterfire_masterのサンプルコードをAndroid Studioで実行させたい

Tags: android-studio, firebase, flutter

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/FlutterFire

上記ページのサンプルコードのフォルダ(flutterfire-master)をダウンロードし、
実行させようとしているのですが、どうすれば実行できるのかよくわかりません。

試しに、
flutterfire-master>packages>firebase_auth
のサンプルをandroidstudioで動かそうとしています。
firebaseのサンプルなのでアプリをfirebaseプロジェクトに登録したりすると思うのですが、
それ以前にまずandroidstudioでどのファイルをどうやって開けばいいのかがわかりません。
開き方を教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

それはサンプルコードではないです。Firebase関連のパッケージをまとめたものです。

Answer (score 0):

サンプルディレクトリのパスが間違っていないでしょうか？
`lutterfire-master > packages > firebase_auth > firebase_auth > example`

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example